# Correcting Webkit Vertical Alignment Issue with <sup> and CSS vertical-align:top on TD

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, superscript

Made a major revision to demonstrate issue and clarify cause in CSS:

Chrome and Safari display this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
BODY { background:#fff; }
.survey_table TD {
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="survey_table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
2. Are you familiar with the <a href="http://example.com">Louisiana Sanitary Code</a><sup>1</sup> requirements for laboratories to report notifiable (reportable) conditions to the Louisiana Office of Public Health?
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this:

[image: screenshot of chrome]

Firefox and IE display it like this:

[image: screenshot of firefox]

The issue is coming from the CSS on the TD `vertical-align:top;`  Does anyone know how to get Webkit browsers to display  like FF and IE and preserve the CSS vertical-alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and decided to use relative positioning;

[Wrong rendering of <sup> in table with valign=top in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741898/wrong-rendering-of-sup-in-table-with-valign-top-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: Thanks!  This will come in handy!

Answer (score 2):

since it works fine everywhere else other than tables, I just did this:

```
table sup {
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.6em;
```

Gives an acceptable result in both Chrome & Explorer